# Populating a listview contents with an array

Tags: arrays, listview, jquery-mobile

I have created a function that would be able to place the array contents into a listview, Here is my progress so far.

```
<div id="MainPage" data-role="page" >

    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#ViewPage" data-role="button" onClick="displayArray( )">RENAME</a>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="ViewPage" data-role="page" >

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="viewlist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Sample Contents" data-inset="true">
                 <!-- array contents goes here -->
        </ul>   
    </div>

</div>  

<script>

     var sampleContent = new Array( );

    displayArray( )
    {
        for(var scan=0; scan<sampleContent.length; detect++)
        {
             $('#viewlist').append('<li><a href="#">' + sampleContent[scan] + '</a></li>');
        }       
    }

</script>
```

My code works during the first press of the button but when i pressed it the second time, the list view becomes messed up.

Any help or advice will be glady accepted thanks in advance.

---

edited, i have figured out how to do it but I am having problems during the second press of the button.

Comment: Populate your listview with an `ArrayAdapter` and set `sampleContent` as list for the adapter so it knows what to fill the listview with. Weird android code btw

Answer (score 1):

First of i don't want to be rude but i think you should start first to read some basics about android.

Like: 
 Android Activities , life cycle of activities
 Layout in Android (how to add button on an activity then respond to a click etc) , different existing Layout in android and android widget (like the listView for example)

of course there are a lot more to read but it s a good way to start.

However i will provide you codes that will do what you are asking for and i will try to explain as much as i can

First of all you need to create the other activity and inside the layout of that activity insert a listview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then the java code of the other activity will look like this

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
    //create the array adapter that will input your array and convert it into a list of view  

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    String[] list;

    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // get the array from ressource and insert them on an array
        list =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray);

        // then create the arrayadpater with input your array of string if you dont get                     //anything here just read android documentation about arrayAdapter
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list );

        //then set the adapter to your listView
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }


}
```

res xml file

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="listArray">
        <item>Apple</item>
        <item>Banana</item>
        <item>Cherry</item>
        <item>Cranberry</item>
        <item>Grape</item>
        <item>Grape</item>
    </string-array>
</resources
```

>

Hope it will help

Comment: i get an x icon with these 2 lines of code "findViewById(R.id.listView);" and "getStringArray(R.array.listArray);" saying cannot be resolved or is not a field. What quick fix should i set them?

Comment: First tell me what IDE are you using, just to be clear we are talking about android right? If you like i can post the entire source code

Comment: i think i am using jquery-mobile. i just started learning about this. because i never touched the java code or the xml. i should replace android with jquery-mobile. i was confused i am sorry.

Comment: my answer was useful to you?

Comment: it gave me a some info, but i guess it is not what i am looking for since i was using jquery-mobile in the first place. My apologies, but I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.listview('refresh')` after you have added all items.

```
$('#viewlist').listview('refresh');
```

If you want to empty the list each time and refill it, call .empty() before the for loop:

```
$('#viewlist').empty();
```

To use better jquery mobile coding, structure your code like this:

Take the onclick out of the anchor tag and add an id:

```
<a id="viewPageBtn" href="#ViewPage" data-role="button" >RENAME</a>
```

In your script tag, handle pagecreate on the main page, and within it handle the click event of the anchor:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#MainPage", function(){
    var sampleContent = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
    $("#viewPageBtn").on("click", function(){
        $('#viewlist').empty();
        for(var scan=0; scan < sampleContent.length; scan++)
        {
             $('#viewlist').append('<li><a href="#">' + sampleContent[scan] + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');
        }
        $('#viewlist').listview('refresh');
    });
});
```